# 2D Coordinate Transformation

Tags: coordinates, transformation, rotational-matrices

I have a global coordinate system that I need to transform to a local coordinate system. The new and old coordinate systems are shown below.

[image]

Using transformation rules, I came with with the coordinates in the new system. These formulas are shown below.

[image]

These formulas are not working, and I'm not sure why? As test points I tried out these,

Old System (0,-1.11270165)

New System (5.88729835,-10)

If anyone can enlighten me it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are your coordinates cartesian? Otherwise these formaluars are false. And: Do you use radians or degrees? Nearly ever programming language uses radians, so you might need to check this (as you gave the angels in degrees)!

Comment: Actually, in the program I don't use angles explicitly. Since the edges are all either horizontal or vertical, I just use 0's and 1's stored in a vector for values of cosine and sine. Technically you are correct, I just didn't think about it when posting the question. The coordinates are Cartesian.